# How to return the table within a div through a select with a specific selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the table `options` through the select `question-picker`:

I did this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var question_container = $('.question-picker option[value="1"]').parent();
  console.log(question_container);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card question">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="questions" class="control-label">Question</label>
          <select class="form-control question-picker required" data-max-options="1"><optgroup label="health"><option value="1">How old are you?</option><option value="2">What is your name?</option></optgroup><optgroup label="family"><option value="1">How old are your?</optgroup></select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <table class="table options">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td><label>Option</label></td>
                <td><label>Related question</label></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is that I get the optgroup not the table parent.
This is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8pmLrso7/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var question_container = $('.question-picker option[value="1"]').closest('.row').next().find('table.options');
  console.log('Length:',question_container.length); //1
  console.log('Tag Name:',question_container[0].tagName); //TABLE
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card question">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="questions" class="control-label">Question</label>
          <select class="form-control question-picker required" data-max-options="1"><optgroup label="health"><option value="1">How old are you?</option><option value="2">What is your name?</option></optgroup><optgroup label="family"><option value="1">How old are your?</optgroup></select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <table class="table options">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td><label>Option</label></td>
                <td><label>Related question</label></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but this return the form, should I use find?

Comment: @zparo, which element do you want with the selector?

Comment: the table with class `options`

Comment: this return length 0 so no element found :|

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var question_container = $('.question-picker').closest("div[class='row']").next().find("table")
```